# deformed rectangulars with decreasing trend

Tags: python, forms, matplotlib, rectangles

i have to implement some figures like that on the Picture with python (matplotlib).

[image: Picture]

Has anyone an idea how i could achieve this? I tried to work with polygons to create these deformed rectangulars, for example like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.axes()

points = [[x, y]]    
polygon = plt.Polygon(points)

plt.show()
```

but it just shows a coordinate system and nothing else when I type in the x,y points to get a deformed rectangular.

## Edit

I now used the answer by @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, but throws an error

[image: Picture]

Does anyone have an idea where this comes from?

Comment: The error you see is a Python 2/3 thing. The zip(x,y) function returns a iterator. Convert it to a list as such: list(zip(x,y,))

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to add a polygon to a matplotlib axes. The polygon is an instance of `matplotlib.patches.Polygon` and it is appended to the axes using `ax.add_patch`.

Since matplotlib does not autoscale the axes to include patches, it is necessary to set the axis limits.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches

x = [1,10,10,1,1]
y = [2,1,5,4,2]
points = list(zip(x,y))

polygon = matplotlib.patches.Polygon(points, facecolor="#aa0088")

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_aspect("equal")
ax.add_patch(polygon)

ax.set_xlim(0,11)
ax.set_ylim(0,6)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help but I get an error:

----> 9 polygon = matplotlib.patches.Polygon(points, facecolor="#aa0088")

...\patches.py in __init__(self, xy, closed, **kwargs)
    937         Patch.__init__(self, **kwargs)
    938         self._closed = closed
--> 939         self.set_xy(xy)

...\patches.py in set_xy(self, xy)
   1001         xy = np.asarray(xy)
   1002         if self._closed:
-> 1003             if len(xy) and (xy[0] != xy[-1]).any():
   1004                 xy = np.concatenate([xy, [xy[0]]])
   1005         else:

TypeError: len() of unsized object

Comment: Ardian needs a `points=list(zip(x,y))` for the code to work in python 3, per Simon's comment at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42875357/deformed-rectangulars-with-decreasing-trend#comment78749744_42875357