# Matplotlib plots turn out blank

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to plot circles in matplotlib, but the outcome is always an empty plot.

E.g.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import matplotlib.collections as mcollections

fig = plt.figure()
fig.set_size_inches(18.5, 10.5, forward=True)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')

x = np.array([17., 29., 41.,  3., 15.])
y = np.array([21., 41., 30., 19., 5.])
r = np.array([22.8035085, 46.04345773, 46.61544808, 16.,  12.16552506])

patches = [mpatches.Circle((xx, yy), rr) for xx, yy, rr in zip(x, y, r)]
collection = mcollections.PatchCollection(patches)
ax.add_collection(collection) 

fig.savefig("test.png")
```

This produces an empty plot, the same when I try with add_artist. Hopefully someone can point me to where I am going wrong! Thank you

Comment: Same issue as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42875357/deformed-rectangulars-with-decreasing-trend

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In addition to the other answer provided, you can use `ax.autoscale()` before saving the plot. that will result in

[image]

Comment: Cool, better than my answer. *Simple is better than complex*.

Comment: Thanks!! I didn't know patches behave that way

Answer (score 5):

Your problem here is not the paches haven't been drawed. The reason your plot is blank is that **matplotlib didn't auto-adjust the axis according to the range of  your patches.**

Usually, it will do the auto-adjust jobs with some main plot functions, such as `plt.plot(), plt.scatter() ...`. As far as I'm concerned, it's not designed for drawing geometric figures like *triangles, rectangle and circles*. This may also explain why this called `patches` in `matplotlib`.

So what you need to do is to specify the range of the axis manully by using something like this in your case:

```
plt.axis([-50, 100, -50, 100])
```